wordpress admin is filled with errors
https://www.herequestrian.com/wp-admin/ I get errors. I installed SEOPress plugin and since then I am plagued with error issues and I can't get into my dashboard. It's one big mess! I get pages and pages of this: WordPress database error: [CREATE command denied to user 'u740200033_Jy2Be'@'127.0.0.1' for table u740200033_vyaK4.wp_amz_assets]
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_amz_assets ( id BIGINT(15) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, post_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, asset VARCHAR(225) NULL DEFAULT NULL, thumb VARCHAR(225) NULL DEFAULT NULL, download_status VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT 'new' COMMENT 'new, success, inprogress, error, remote', hash VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL, media_id BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT '0', msg TEXT NULL, date_added DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL, date_download DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL, image_sizes TEXT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), INDEX post_id (post_id), INDEX hash (hash), INDEX media_id (media_id), INDEX download_status (download_status) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
I tried with my host Hostinger, but they couldn't help. I don't know what to do

Log in to your file manager and delete the plugin.
